# How to find JsonPath if the response is in form of array?

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am using rest assured library in java and I am trying to get the response from an endpoint. Here is the code for that

```
package practice;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;

import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.path.json.JsonPath;

public class GoRestGetRequest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        RestAssured.baseURI="https://gorest.co.in";
        
        String response=given().
        log().
        all().
        when().
        get("/public/v2/users").
        then().
        log().
        all().
        assertThat().
        statusCode(200).
        extract().
        response().
        asString();
        JsonPath js=new JsonPath(response);
        int id= js.getInt("$[0].id");
        System.out.println(id);
        
    }

}
```

I an getting answer in the form of array with square brackets. Normally there won't be any square brackets. how to parse response if array has square brackets.

```
[
{
    "id": 3234,
    "name": "Chandran Embranthiri",
    "email": "chandran_embranthiri@conn.name",
    "gender": "male",
    "status": "inactive"
},
{
    "id": 3233,
    "name": "Sharmila Sharma",
    "email": "sharmila_sharma@marquardt.name",
    "gender": "male",
    "status": "active"
},
{
    "id": 3232,
    "name": "Agnivesh Chopra V",
    "email": "v_agnivesh_chopra@corkery-boehm.co",
    "gender": "female",
    "status": "inactive"
}]
```

If I try to fetch the id with `$[0].id` then I am getting `nullPointerException`
Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Without the square brackets that isn't valid JSON. I would just add the square brackets to `response` myself before passing it to `JsonPath`, or tell the owner of the endpoint to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to change to make your code work is: `$[0].id` --> `[0].id`